# JS Удалить все символы в строке после последнего числа

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть стройка вида 100-200,,,,,
Нужно удалить все после 200, при этом строка может быть 100-200,200-300,,,, и т.д.
Т.е. нужно взять последнее число (можно определить что это 0) и убрать все что после него

У меня же получается только убрать все кроме цифр

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы удалить и до, и после:

```js
console.log(
  ',,100-200,200-300,,'.replace(/^\D+|\D+$/g, '')
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Подсказали

```
str.replace(/\D+$/, '');
```

Только вот еще вопрос
Как убрать все до первого числа?

,,100-200,200-300,, превратить в 100-200,200-300

Comment: Отформатируйте код с помощью [кнопки править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1143909/edit)